# Detecting text overflow in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, overflow

I have made this element such that if the value prop text overflows out of its element, it will not be visible. However, I need to make it such that if an overflow occurs, I take the last three characters and replace them with "...". So for example, value="This is an example" but the 'example' is overflowing ("This is an" is the only thing displaying). I need to display "this is..." now since the three dots have to take up space. Let me know if I need to clarify, thank you!

tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import "./DispalyValueControl-styles.scss"

export interface DisplayValueControlProps {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

export class DisplayValueControl extends React.Component<DisplayValueControlProps, any> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="display-value">
                <div className="value"> {this.props.value} </div>
                <div className="info-label"> {this.props.label} </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

css:

```
.display-value {    
    >.value {
        color: #444444;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 22px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text-overflow : ellipsis;` property of CSS.

However, along with it, you also need to add `overflow` and `white-space` properties for it to take effect

Eg :

```
.display-value {    
    >.value {
        color: #444444;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Check out the [browser compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).
(You may need to use `-ms-text-overflow` and `-o-text-overflow` for some versions of IE and Opera respectively as mentioned in the above link.)